# Blank cells in matrix take on average of surrounding cells in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a matrix of numbers in excel that contains several blank cells. The numbers correspond to the clay level in the ground, as indicated by a borehole in that position. I am using the cells as a grid to represent a map. I want to replace the blank cells with an average of all of the cells which surround it. How do I do this? I keep getting circular reference errors when I try to do it.

Comment: I think you will need VBA

Answer (score 0):

**1) Use a proxy rang**e: Create a duplicate range and have that refer to the original. The named range here is F5:H6

[image: Named range]

For above the range on the left (F5:H6) is called namedRange and the blank cell in the duplicate range on the right uses Average(namedRange) to populate the value.

To add a named range , select your range and then add the name via the [name manager](http://www.contextures.com/xlNames01.html)   .

**OR**

**2) Use VBA**

With VBA using the same named range (code in a standard module - replace activesheet with your sheetname) :

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

With ActiveSheet.Range("namedRange")
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(.Value)
End With

End Sub
```